# How do i str_split text character according to multiple record in query

Tags: php, split, character

I have example 2,1,3,2 record for the query `$qty` in my solution i want to split each 4 diffrent characters from the text line of **1234567810111213141516171819202122232425262728** just  according to each record in `$qty` in achievement my expected output should look like 1234,5678,9101,1121,3141,5161,7181,9202
i have tried:

```
<?php
require("init.php");
?>
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from books where book='1644445'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$qty  = $row["quantity"];  
echo "<br/>$qty"; #result 2132
$plit = "1234567810111213141516171819202122232425262728";
$show_plit = str_split($plit, 4);
for($b = 0; $b<$qty; $b++)
{
echo "<br/>$show_plit[$b]";
}
}
?>
```

but i get 1234,5678,1234,1234,5678,9101,1234,5678 in output what are mine doing wrong.
Big thanks in advances

Comment: It might just be me, but I have absolutely no idea what you're asking here. Please edit your question and try to make it clearer. What is that input? Why are you using it? The value you have in bold is not the same as the value in the code, should it be? What's the database query there for? What do you mean by "I have example 2,1,3,2 record for the query"?

Comment: So far i figured that his string is `$plit = '';for ($i = 1; $i <= 28; $i++) $plit .= $i;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you generate the array from the `str_split` in every and iterateit each time starting form 0, you only take the first elements. By taking it out of the `while` loop and saving the old count of b outside the loop as well, your code will not start from the beginning again.

But be warned, you will run into an `OutOfBoundsException`, if your book qunatity sum is higher than the available number of blocks from your initial string.

Also your string is missing a 9:
12345678**9**10111213141516171819202122232425262728

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from books where book='1644445'");
$split = "12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728";
$show_plit = str_split($split, 4);
$b = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $qty  = $row["quantity"];  
    $oldB = $b;
    echo "<br/>{$qty}"; #result 2132
    for(; $b< $oldB + $qty; $b++)
    {
        echo "<br/>{$show_plit[$b]}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though this might be what you are looking for, i still do not have the slightest clou about what you want to achieve with this.

Comment: Thanks allot for the great solution knowledged today but can i update this output to database according to each qty output? E:g
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE books SET output='$each_output' WHERE quantity=$qty");
 i tried but i get only the last record of each output updated into the database example 5678,9101,5161,9202

Comment: @KingsleyPlaza Create a variable before the `for`loop that saves the corresponging blocks and update the db with that variable:
`$output = ''; for(;$b < $oldB + $qty; $b++) {$output .= $show_plit[$b];} mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE books SET output='$output' WHERE quantity=$qty");`

Comment: Yes very wise never thought at $output = ' ';
big thanks for the knowledge